# Configure DataTables to handle array of arrays

Tags: datatables

Is it possible to configure `DataTables` to hanlde array of objects instead of default array of arrays for `aaData` propery?

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "sEcho": 1,
    "iTotalRecords": "57",
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": "57",
    "aaData": [
        {
            "userid": "tM4Ga0zX",
            "password": "ZKwMEiIa",
            "vpn_password": "K3lS2yn9",
            "status_id": 0,
            "expire_account": "0000-01-01 00:00:00",
            "created": "2014-02-11 09:29:02"
        },
        {
            "userid": "tM4Ga0zX",
            "password": "ZKwMEiIa",
            "vpn_password": "K3lS2yn9",
            "status_id": 0,
            "expire_account": "0000-01-01 00:00:00",
            "created": "2014-02-11 09:29:02"
        },
        {
            "userid": "tM4Ga0zX",
            "password": "ZKwMEiIa",
            "vpn_password": "K3lS2yn9",
            "status_id": 0,
            "expire_account": "0000-01-01 00:00:00",
            "created": "2014-02-11 09:29:02"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, add an `aoColumns`-definition your initialization :

```js
..
"aoColumns": [
  { "mDataProp": "userid" }, 
  { "mDataProp": "password" },
  { "mDataProp": "vpn_password" },
  { "mDataProp": "status_id" },
  { "mDataProp": "expire_account" },
  { "mDataProp": "created" }
]
..
```

fiddle with your data as above -> **http://jsfiddle.net/6tK7K/**

**Important** : If you use dataTables v 1.9.2 or above, use the property name `"mData"` instead. As [the docs says](http://datatables.net/usage/columns) :

> Note that prior to DataTables 1.9.2 mData was called mDataProp. The
>   name change reflects the flexibility of this property and is
>   consistent with the naming of mRender. If 'mDataProp' is given, then
>   it will still be used by DataTables, as it automatically maps the old
>   name to the new if required.

Comment: Thanks! How does jsfiddle work if there is no `DataTables` plugin included?

Comment: You are welcome! See the fiddle, to the left there is "External Resources", just added datatables.js and the corresponding css from a CDN. Allan Jardine has now his own CDN up running, http://cdn.datatables.net/ - but I think it is still in a kind of beta.